# Flagging Dates with intck (SAS)

Tags: date, sas

Another question:

I'm trying to flag 30 days of data in my SAS code.

```
Person Day 1 Release Date Sales
Person Day 2 Release Date Sales
```

So, I've created a flag that says if `Release Date = Day 1`, then `flag = 1 else flag = 0`.

I need to count 30 days after the `flag = 1`.  I used to do this with intck in SAS but lost all of my code and I can't remember how to get it right.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggest you show some sample input records, and the desired output.  If you have date variables and want to count days, you can use subtraction instead of INTCK.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `INTNX()` function instead.

```
day1='01MAY2015'd ;
day30 = intnx('day',day1,30);
```